# Phonegap - capturing the response body of a request

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to capture the response body of a request using PhoneGap?  I am trying to upload a file and I need to see what is being sent/recieved.  I am having a hellish time trying to figure this out one out.

```
 var ft = new FileTransfer();
    console.log("file transfer created...");
    ft.upload(imageURI, serverURI, function(r){console.log("Response = " + r.response);}, function(error){console.log(error);alert('Error uploading image')}, options);
```

this is the response that I am printing from the server printed to the weinre console:

```
bytesSent: 13148
response: "[]"
responseCode: 200
```

I am using weinre to inspect any logs and other info, but that is not enough.  I really need to see the request, similar to what firebug would have.  Any help would be awesome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to setup [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/) to see what is going on between the client and the server. The response is whatever the serverURI sends back to the device. It won't show you what has been sent.

Comment: Ahh damn, that's what I was afraid of.  Wireshark is brutal.  That's really annoying when you are are trying to debug something you can't really test in the browser like the camera...  Well thanks for the input!  I am gonna leave this open for a bit in case anyone else has any input.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It turned out upload uri redirected requet to the login page.